# How to get the location/Fullpath property of the .msg file from Outlook 2007 addin

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I open the .msg file from My Documents and i need to get the location/fullpath of the .msg file.

I have a piece of code here to capture the MailItem open event but I don't know what to do next to get the location or fullpath of the .msg file

```
class MailItemHelper
{
    Outlook.MailItem _MailItem = null;

    public MailItemHelper(Outlook.MailItem mailItem)
    {
        _MailItem = mailItem;
        ((ItemEvents_10_Event)_MailItem).Open += new ItemEvents_10_OpenEventHandler(MailItemHelper_Open);
    }

    void MailItemHelper_Open(ref bool Cancel)
    {
        string msgPath = _MailItem.???
    }
}
```

Regards